# ¿Cómo mantener los datos en el view con dos parámetros de búsqueda al hacer click en un link para hacer otro filtro en Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo un problema primero les muestro el view create
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Primer paso: elijo la fecha y click en Buscar itinerario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Segundo paso: Elijo el itinerario generado por el filtrado de fecha y hago click en Asignar Asiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tercer paso: Elijo un asiento y debe aparecerme la sección 2 con el número de asiento elegido en la sección 3 que son un grupo de links.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en cada link del croquis esta conformado por este código;

```
<a href="{{ action('PasajeController@create', ['nroAsiento' => '4']) }}" class="asiento-vacio btn btn-default" value="4" title="4" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window"></span></br>4</a>
```

Y pues si me envía el número de asiento que los capturo en el controlador para después enviarlo nuevamente al view create para q se visualice en el input de Número de asiento; pero lo que hace es hacer un reload de la vie create y mis filstros iniciales se pierden,

Este es el código de la sección 1 de los filtros:

```
{!! Form::model(Request::all(), ['route' => 'generar.pasaje.create', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::date('searchItinFecha', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class' => 'form-control', 'value' => $searchItinFecha ]) !!}
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    {!! Form::submit('Buscar Itinerario', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <select name="searchItin" class="form-control">
                   @forelse ($itinerarios as $itin)
                        <option value="{{$itin->ItinCodigo}}" @if ($itin->ItinCodigo == $searchItin)) {{'selected'}}@elseif($itin->ItinCodigo == old('searchItin')){{'selected'}}@endif>{{$itin->TryDescripcion}} -- {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($itin->ItinHora)->format('h:i a') }}</option>
                    @empty
                        <option value="">No hay Itinerarios</option>
                    @endforelse
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-btn" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                    {!! Form::submit('Asignar Asiento', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> **Por favor ayúdenme a solucionarlo...**

Comment: mmmm , para hacer filtros sin recargar el sitio , ajax es una opción mas sencilla y si quieres algo mas elaborado vue js , pero este ultimo te llevas ma tiempo aprenderlo.

Comment: Hola @Sebastián, ok también lo intenté con ajax y me rellena el input de número de asiento; pero el siente paso q es buscar al pasajero por número de documento, pues el valor del ajax se pierde. ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se pierda ese valor?