# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un link y pasarlo a un input con Vuejs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Necesito que al hacer click en un enlace el valor de este se debe reflejar en un input y mantener ese valor así la página haga un reload, a menos que al hacer click en otro link me cambie por el valor de ese otro link.

Comment: Podes mostrar que llevas hecho hasta ahora? si la pagina hace un reload, las variables se pierden, salvo que las guardes en otro lado.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, mira en este enlace esta mi pregunta original hecha en Laravel, hasta que alguien me sugirió probar con vuejs: (https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177860/90144)

Comment: si pero si haces reload todo empieza de vuelta.. con vue vas a poder hacer eso facil... pero lo del reload es mas complicado...

Comment: Ese es el detalle, es que en laravel cuando hago la consulta por un pasajero a un controller filtrado por su documento regresa la data; pero cuando hace el return desde el controlador, la pagina hace un reload y value del input Nro de Asiento que fue asignado haciendo click en un link, se pierde :(  Sólo necesito que ese valor no se pierda...  T.T

Comment: ¿Hay algún modo de settear un valor a una variable en vuejs y q este no pierda su valor aún haciendo reload?

Comment: si la guardas fuera del navegador o en el store del navegador supongo que si. nunca hice algo asi...

Comment: Gracias por la genial idea @gbianchi, ya lo solucioné :)